# The simplest way to enable form submit button when text input is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ecmascript-6

I would like to disable the `submit` button until all text `inputs` are filled. My code example below isn’t working.

What is the simplest and most idiomatic way to achieve this and what am I missing?

```js
const form = document.forms[0]
const inputs = form.querySelector("fieldset > *")
const submit = form.querySelector("[type=submit]")

inputs.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (!inputs.length) {
    submit.disabled = true
  } else {
    submit.disabled = false
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="name"><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="john@example.com" id="email"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." id="message"></textarea>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

*I'm aware that there are numerous questions and answers on Stack Overflow about this, but most are needlessly complicated.*

Comment: You'd have to listen for change on each input and then when change happens iterate over the inputs to see if they have a value then do your if/else.

Comment: @FunkDoc So I should start with `inputs.forEach(input => {`?

Comment: Or just use HTML5 resources, adding "required" attribute to each tag.

Comment: @FabioManzano I’m aware of `required` attribute, but in this instance, I need to disable the `submit` button until text `inputs` are filled.

Comment: you can use oninput to fire a function that goes through the inputs https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably similar to the other solutions, I tested this in JSFiddle so I know it works at least.

```
const form = document.forms[0];
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("fieldset > input, fieldset > textarea");
const submit = form.querySelector("[type=submit]");

for (i in inputs) {
    var _input = inputs[i];

    if (typeof _input == 'object') {
    _input.addEventListener("change", () => {
      submit.disabled = false;

      for (i in inputs) {
        var _input = inputs[i];

        if (typeof _input == 'object') {
          if (_input.value == '') {
            submit.disabled = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/un1m5jgq/13/

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function to check if the inputs are empty. Then just make that function the callback for the form inputs.

EDIT:

If you have an array of inputs you can use for loops and replace all the individual input variables.

```js
let form = document.forms[0]
let nameInp = document.getElementById('name');
let emailInp = document.getElementById('email');
let messageInp = document.getElementById('message');

let submit = form.querySelector("[type=submit]")

function checkInputs() {
  if (nameInp.value != "" && emailInp.value != "" && messageInp.value != "") {
    
    submit.disabled = false;
    
  } else if(!(nameInp.value != "" && emailInp.value != "" && messageInp.value != "")){
    
    submit.disabled = true;
    
  }
}

nameInp.addEventListener("change",checkInputs);
emailInp.addEventListener("change",checkInputs);
messageInp.addEventListener("change",checkInputs);
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="name"><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="john@example.com" id="email"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." id="message"></textarea>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have select all `inputs/textareas` inside `fieldset` by `querySelectorAll` and loop `for each` values.

You should try below code to get what you want. You can use Jquery to make it much simple.

```js
const form = document.forms[0]
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll("fieldset > input, fieldset > textarea"),result;
const submit = form.querySelector("[type=submit]")
console.log(inputs);
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
          if (!inputs[j].value.length) {
            submit.disabled = true
            return;
          } else {
            submit.disabled = false
          }
        }
  });
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="name"><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="john@example.com" id="email"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." id="message"></textarea>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```